# Django Rest Framework how to post date field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to post JSON request with field `date`:

```
{
    "date":"2015-02-11T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

It's the string is automatically converted from `Date` object and I don't want to crop the part `T00:00:00.000Z` manually at frontend.

But if I post such request, Django Rest Framework validator of DateField will say me, that date has invalid format.

My model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField('Date', blank=True, null=True)
```

My serializer:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'date')
```

What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: How does your model look like?

Comment: Added the model definition to my question.

Comment: Can you please also post your serializer?

Comment: Does it work if you pass a date generated with `datetime.datetime.now()`? If not, try to use a `DateTimeField` instead of a `DateField`.

Comment: Added serializer to the question.

Comment: How are you generating the `date` value that you are POSTing? It looks to me like you're using `datetime` not `date`...

Comment: I generate the date value at the frontend side. For example, like that `new Date(2018,1,5)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can modify your date field in your serializer with a different format (different from the default one, which you are using implicitly).

More info:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datefield

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```
from rest_framework import serializers, fields


class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    date = fields.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'])

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'date')
```

Note that if you need to parse timestamps other than in UTC (Z at the end of your timestamp), you will need to customize `DateField` a bit more.

As @nitrovatter mentioned in the comments, the date input formats can also be configured in the settings to affect every serializer by default. For example:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ['iso-8601', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'],
}
```

Comment: Is the code of the serializer correct? Should it be `date = DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'])`?

Comment: This works for example: `datetime.strptime("2015-02-11T00:00:00.000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")`. But note that the `Z` is hardcoded, see my last paragraph. Do you need to parse any possible timezone ?

Comment: In my specific case, I may not parse any possible timezones. But if it's easy to make the general solution for all timezones, I would know it.

Comment: Also, I've fixed the typo, you were right: I missed the `date = ` bit

Comment: Tested on the shell: `EventSerializer(data={'date': '2015-02-11T00:00:00.000Z'}).is_valid()` returns True.
But this `EventSerializer(data={'date': '__WRONG__'}).is_valid()` return False and the error that you mention is stored in serializer.errors.

Comment: Yeah! It works! Sorry for false statement before and thank you very much! I've added the following string to config, to deliver me from necessity to add that string in each serializator: `REST_FRAMEWORK  = {
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ['iso-8601', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ']
}`

Comment: Oh yes, that's also possible. I will add it to the answer in case someone else needs it.