# Django DateTime serializing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

im getting a strange serialized representation of my DateTimeField, at the ending of the representation I get a "**-05:00**" on the JSON.

Inside my model the field is defined as:

```
ultima_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And in the serializer I got it inside the `Meta Class`:

```
class Meta:
    fields = (
        ...
        'ultima_actualizacion',
        ...
         )
```

But when I make a request in the response JSON I get something like:

```
 {
 ...
 "ultima_actualizacion": "2019-08-07T15:34:22.692530-05:00"
 }
```

Which seems odd because I haven't changed the format and still get that "**-05:00**" in every *ultima_actualizacion*

I have looked and tried changing the format and input formats as specified in: [Django Rest Framework Fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) and in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434094/django-rest-framework-how-to-post-date-field) but still get the "**-05:00**"

Comment: -5:00 is the timezone setting in which your server is configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's `DateTimeField` is a zone-aware object which means: it stores timezone information in the date object.

**-5:00** is your server's timezone setting.

If you don't want this to happen, configure your project settings to use UTC timezone by adding this to `settings.py`

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Edit:

As suggested by ipaleka, you can totally disable timezone by adding `USE_TZ = False` to settings.py instead.

Comment: Actually `USE_TZ = False` should be set for such a case.

Comment: @ipaleka thank you for the notice, I updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: works like a charm thank you, just a quick question, for what does the 'UTC' stand for?