# Django Rest Framework Date field serialization problems

Tags: json, django, date, django-rest-framework

im trying to post the recruitment date of an employee , but i keep having the 400 bad request error and recruitment_date: ["This field is required."] ,after searching i added the Date Formats on the settings but i still have the same error

views.py :

```
class CreateEmployee(generics.CreateAPIView):
    lookup_field= 'pk'
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Employee.objects.all()
```

serializers.py :

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url         = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    recruitment_date =fields.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d",input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields =['url','id','f_name','l_name','job','telephone','recruitment_date','salary']

    def get_url(self,obj):

        request = self.context.get("request")
        return obj.get_api_url(request=request)
```

settings.py :

```
"DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": ["iso-8601","%Y-%m-%d"],
```

Comment: Are you using `serializers.DateField`?

Comment: No ,fields.datefield

Comment: Where are you importing "fields" from?

Comment: I did follow thia answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434094/django-rest-framework-how-to-post-date-field/53434632

Comment: Can you share the view? How are you calling the view and with what data?

Comment: i added the view.py

Comment: Looks like you send request without required parameter `recruitment_date `, could u provide something how you making this request? Do you use REST-client, DRF browsable api or curl to post the request?

Comment: I found the solution , it was in the axios post method i didnt respect the required parameters ,cuz i didnt use the method axios.post , i did an instance of the object axios then i have to add the headers manually